# Como criar um popup que fica piscando na tela?

Tags: javascript, html

Criei um *popup*, mas agora o cliente quer que ele fique piscando até ser fechado. Só informando que é uma imagem JPEG que abre na tela.

Comment: Ezequiel, te convido a fazer o [tour] para aprender como o site funciona e ler o guia de [ask]. Por favor, melhore sua pergunta adicionando o código HTML referente ao pop-up utilizado e, de preferência, crie um [mcve].

Answer (score 14):

O infógrafo abaixo demonstra o quanto o uso dessa técnica para chamar atenção é elegante, agradável, e recomendado nos *papers* escritos sobre experiência de usuário e design de interfaces:

[image: Satan Mouse]

Se você já negociou sua alma imortal com o Satanás e não vê problemas em seguir adiante, você tem duas formas de proceder:

#### Forma maldita 1:

Essa forma só funciona se o *popup* estiver no mesmo domínio da aba ou janela que o abre. Na página principal, utilize o seguinte código:

```
var janelaParaOInferno = window.open(url);
setInterval(function () { janelaParaOInferno.focus() }, 300);
```

#### Forma maldita 2:

No *popup*, inclua o seguinte código:

```
var LuciferEhMeuSenhor = function () {
    window.blur();
    window.focus();
}

setInterval(LuciferEhMeuSenhor, 300);
```

## Aviso aos acólitos

Os anjos do bem têm trabalhado para que gambiarras como essas não sejam capazes de afetar os inocentes. Há anos elas não funcionam no Chrome, por exemplo. Essas coisas do mal só funcionarão no ambiente de empresas que não permitem que seus funcionários utilizem navegadores e sistemas operacionais modernos. Se o seu empregador acorrenta as almas torturadas ao IE8, vá em frente... Caso contrário você está abandonado à própria sorte.

Comment: +666 Excelente.

Comment: +1 Recomendo usar fonte ComicSans para ganhar pontos extras com o Senhor das Trevas.

Comment: Pra complementar, coloca um 'alert' disparado com 'onbeforeunload' dentro dessa janela aberta pra terem certeza que querem sair da página.

Answer (score 1):

Com o código abaixo você consegue um efeito em JavaScript que faz o elemento ficar como se estivesse piscando:

```
var piscando = document.getElementById('id_do_elemento');
var interval = window.setInterval(function(){
    if(piscando.style.visibility == 'hidden'){
        piscando.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }else{
        piscando.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}, 700);
```

```js
var piscando = document.getElementById('id_do_elemento');
var interval = window.setInterval(function(){
    if(piscando.style.visibility == 'hidden'){
        piscando.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }else{
        piscando.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}, 700);
```

```html
<img id="id_do_elemento" height="100" src="https://media.apnarm.net.au/media/images/2016/11/22/b88450493z1_20161122153435_000g7odij2q50-0-z20cq7ifsjegh26w9n2_t620.jpg" />
```

Comment: Desculpe a minha ignorância, mas como não entendo muito de javascript onde uso esse código? num arquivo .js ou entre as tags <script type="text/javascript"> </script>

Comment: @EzequielSoares Você coloca o código na função que abre o popup.

Answer (score -1):

Uma forma bem simples e abrir um GIF animado no lugar do Jpeg. Você pode criar com alguns aplicativos, ou até mesmo em alguns sites. 
Exemplo:

http://www.apptuts.com.br/tutorial/web/sites-para-criar-gifs-animados/

Se preferir, você pode criar uma função javascript para alterar a imagem ou cor do fundo. Como no exemplo a seguir.

```js
setInterval(function(){blink()}, 1000);


function blink() {
        $("#box").fadeTo(100, 0.1).fadeTo(200, 1.0);
}
```

```css
#boxOfTheHell {
  Background:#ff0000;
  color:#00ff00;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  padding:15px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="boxOfTheHell">
  Exemplo pisca pisca.
</div>
```

Comment: Tenho assim: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup/css/popup.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup/js/popup.js"></script>

Comment: window.onload = function() {

    // open a welcome message as soon as the window loads
    Shadowbox.open({
        content:    '<div align="center"><a onclick="Shadowbox.close()"><iframe allowtransparency="true" width="510" height="500" frameborder="0" src="acesse.html"  marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe></a></div>',
        player:     "html",
        title:      "",
        height:     500,
        width:      510
    });

};
</script>

Comment: Se for mais fácil? Como posso criar um gif que a imagem apaga e acende

Comment: http://www.apptuts.com.br/tutorial/web/sites-para-criar-gifs-animados/

https://www.criarbanner.com.br/criargifs/